# tinymce <span> gets removed when containing <br />

Tags: tinymce

I'm using Tiny 4.9.10 to dynamically generate reports based on templates. Users can create templates which contain placeholders. These placeholders then get swapped out for their actual values when generating the actual report. The placeholders get their style (including font, which is the main issue here) from their enclosing `<span>`-tag.

When replacing the placeholder with their actual value, we use `<br />`-tags to insert new lines, since some of the placeholders are almost full reports on their own which need to be structured.

After the placeholders have all been replaced, we inject this dynamically generated content back into a Tiny editor, so as to allow users to make ad hoc changes to the content.

At this point however we noticed that the `<span>`-tag around a piece of generated content containing `<br />`-tags gets removed. This is a problem, because the style info that was enclosed in this tag gets removed as well, resulting in problems further down the line when generating a PDF.

What I've tried to work around this:

- setting `verify_html` to false
- adding `+span[br]/+span[br /]` to `valid_children`
- setting `forced_root_bloc` to `div`

The first two options did nothing to help me, and while the last one looked promising, it didn't help, because even when using `<div>`, font info gets enclosed into a child `<span>`.

I know this is expected behavior, because `<span>` is an inline tag and so it shouldn't have `<br />` tags as children, but I'm currently at a loss for a workaround which allows me to include `<br />` tags into my dynamically generated content without losing the style (most importantly the font) of the parent tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by replacing the `<span>` tags by `<div>` tags when we swap out the placeholders by using some regex looking for spans that enclose a `<p>...<\p>` or a `<b />`. This stops Tiny from throwing away the `<span>` tags when they contain either of these enclosed tags

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE considers the `<span> <br /> </span>` construct an empty space and deletes it in favor of optimization.

I may be late, but you can also try using this callback in the [`setup`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup) option to stop the editor from removing empty spans:

```
setup: function(editor) {
  editor.on('PreInit', function() {
    editor.schema.getElementRule('span').removeEmpty = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for still answering, I don't think this would have solved my issue however, because there would never be a `<span> [...] <br /> [...] </span>` construction with empty brackets inserted into TinyMCE, the brackets would always have content, so TinyMCE should not consider it empty space. It also didn't remove the tag + content but only the tag itself.